# NSCollectionView selection index

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, programming-languages

How do I find what's selected in a NSCollectionView?

I have a NSCollectionView (binding to a NSCollectionViewItem and a NSArrayController where a NSBox is the root item and changes background when selected) and I can't figure out where to find out which item the user selected.

I tried a few things but all returned null:

- send the NSCollectionViewItem a representedObject message
- send the NSCollectionView a selectionIndexes message
- send the NSArrayController a selectedObjects message
- send the NSArrayController a selectionIndexes message
- send the NSArrayController a selectionIndex message

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As it turned out, I missed a retain to the array bound to the NSArrayController and thus to nil for everything. After some testing, NSCollectionView's selectionIndexes does respond with a NSIntegerSet value, can I could derive the selected index from there.